# Совершенный и несовершенный вид

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Поезжай  - это совершенный или несовершенный вид? Если от глагола "поехать" (СВ) значит и императив "поезжай" (СВ)? А мне почему-то кажется, что "поезжай" - это несовершенный вид.

Comment: Посмотрите [эту ссылку](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=PSWjAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT415&lpg=PT415&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9+%D0%9D%D0%A1%D0%92+%D0%A1%D0%92&source=bl&ots=-z50T7vb3y&sig=ACfU3U3Nnd7QecsoXpAQIMGbx3QvtLdNvQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiyzszA_v7zAhVvposKHSW2ASc4ChDoAXoECCIQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%20%D0%9D%D0%A1%D0%92%20%D0%A1%D0%92&f=false), комментарий 80. Надеюсь, она объяснит, почему СВ в данном случае употребляется (и, следовательно, воспринимается) как НСВ.

Comment: Не представляю, за что кто-то поставил минус этому вопросу.

Comment: Не согласен насчет взаимозаменяемости езжай и поезжай. Например: Езжай в ту сторону, пока ветер не переменится. Поезжай в ту сторону, пока ветер не переменится. 1-е звучит, 2-е - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Проверка очень простая. Глаголы совершенного вида не имеет настоящего времени. "Я поезжаю" - нет такого глагола, значит он СВ.

Я **проговорю** с ним еще пару часов.

Казалось бы, действие в процессе, значит несовершенный вид. Но нет, настоящего времени нет, значит СВ.

Я **порублю** дрова еще пару часов.

Казалось бы, действие в процессе, значит несовершенный вид. Но нет, настоящего времени нет, значит СВ.

Я **поезжу** туда еще пару дней.

Казалось бы, действие в процессе, значит несовершенный вид. Но нет, настоящего времени нет, значит СВ.

Я **езжу** туда уже пару дней.

Казалось бы, действие в процессе, значит несовершенный вид. И действительно, это настоящее время, значит НСВ.

Comment: Но, "езжай" (несовершенный вид) тоже не имеет настоящего времени. Я езжаю - это неправильно.

Comment: Это правильно. См словарь https://endic.ru/ozhegov/Ezzhat-8079.html

Comment: ? Правильно что? Вы меня запутали.

Comment: Слово "езжаю" проскакивает в словарях. Например https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C.
Но даже если мы согласимся, что такого слова нет, тогда, очевидно, его роль играет слово "еду" (так как у ехать, повелительной формы нет, а значит там идет замена на езжай). Таким образом, еду -НСВ, настоящее время от слова езжай. Со словом поезжай такое не работает!

Comment: Большое спасибо, за ваши ответы.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Сейчас посмотрел, есть еще слово "езжу" как вариант настоящего времени у "езжай". Слово же "поезжу", очевидно, не настоящего времени.

Comment: Спасибо! Меня имнересует такой вопрос: если инфинитив СВ то и императив (повелительное наклонение) СВ? Всегда? Или возможны варианты? Поехать (СВ) - поезжай (?), ехать (НСВ) - езжай (НСВ). "Поезжай" мне хочется сказать "что Делай", а не "что Сделай". То есть настоящее время, а, значит НСВ.

Comment: "Поезжай" хочется сказать "Что делай", но это не всегда корректно. Рассмотрите два предложения: "Езжай до тех пор, пока будет желание!" и "Поезжай до тех пор, пока будет желание!". 2-е некорректно, именно потому, что "Поезжай" не отвечает на вопрос "что делай", а отвечает на вопрос "что сделай"

Comment: Спасибо, за вашу помощь. Думаю еще и потому, что приставка "по" - обычно с её помощью образуется СВ.